# Sending csv file in multi-part to server from react

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I have a CSV file which I need to post to an API. I need to send this file in multipart from React. I have tried sending this via the `fetch()` method as is suggested by various other tutorials and websites which shows sending files to a server.

The problem that I am facing is my REST API needs an authorized token in headers, and suggestions state that when sending a multipart request it's best to let the browser set the headers for you rather than creating them yourself.

```
export const authPostFile = (url, formData) => {
  return fetch(url, {
    method: "POST",
    body: formData,
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer MY-CUSTOM-AUTH-TOKEN`
    }
  }).then(res => {
    if (res.ok) {
      return res.json();
    } else {
      if (res.status === 401) 
        return renewAuthToken(authPost, url, formData);
     else 
       return handleErrorResponse(res);
    }
  });
};
```

I am getting a 401 in response. I am new to ReactJS and UI development. Is there anything I am missing in here?

Comment: _“when sending multipart request let the browser set the headers for you rather than creating them yourself”_ - that applies to the `Content-Type` header, because that needs to include the boundary that is used to separate the parts inside the request body; it does not mean that you can not specify other headers yourself. Can you check in browser dev tools what the request headers actually look like?

Comment: Ohh. I was missing the key point then. I made changes suggested by you and @Rory McCrossan and now my request headers looks like :



------WebKitFormBoundarypkQdC3A3LA1tdpan
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="sample (85).csv"
Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel


------WebKitFormBoundarypkQdC3A3LA1tdpan--

Comment: That appears to be the multi-part request body, not the headers.

Comment: Ohhh, my bad. It looks like :


authorization: Bearer MY-CUSTOM-AUTH-TOKEN
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryk0ApRdhgzQk6mWRz
Origin: http://localhost:3000
Referer: http://localhost:3000/some/url
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.86 Safari/537.36

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When adding headers to a `fetch()` request you need to use a `Headers` object, not a plain object. Try this:

```
export const authPostFile = (url, formData) => {
  let authHeader = new Headers({
    "Authorization": `Bearer MY-CUSTOM-AUTH-TOKEN`
  });

  return fetch(url, {
    method: "POST",
    body: formData,
    headers: authHeader 
  }).then(res => {
    if (res.ok) {
      return res.json();
    } else {
      if (res.status === 401) 
        return renewAuthToken(authPost, url, formData);
     else 
       return handleErrorResponse(res);
    }
  });
};
```

For more information on `Headers`, see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#Headers).

Comment: Thanks. This solved and cleared the issue. Thus accepting this answer. There was a glitch in server side which was causing the problem after changing the fron-end code to what was suggested by @Rory McCrossan